# How to grep multiple terms and output in the order of the search?

Tags: macos, unix, command-line, grep

I have tried a few things, but don't seem to be making any progress - I have a text file with some lines of data, and I want some lines of data from that file. Each line has a unique identifier which I can grep.

If I use

```
grep 'name1\|name2\|name3\|name4' file.txt > newfile.txt
```

it does the job and greps the desired lines I want, however, I want the lines in the order in which I specified - from this example I want the name1 lines first, then name2 lines, then name3 lines and finally the name4 lines.

However, say for example in my original file the order of the lines were the name2, followed by the name4, followed by name3, followed by name1, the output file also seems to have the lines in this order.

Is there a way to order the grep easily?

The ids are block-sorted, so all lines with name1 for example occur next to each other.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: I am afraid `grep` does not support this requirement. You may have to loop through the words and grep one word at a time.

Answer (score 7):

### Use Loop to Read Words from File

Given a file of words to grep for such as the following:

```
root
lp
syslog
nobody
```

you can use a read loop to repeatedly grep for fixed strings in another file. For example, using Bash shell's default *REPLY* variable and a word file stored in the `/tmp` directory, this will work:

```
while read; do
    grep --fixed-strings "$REPLY" /etc/passwd
done < /tmp/words
```

### Notes

1. The posted example won't prevent multiple matches, but it *will* ensure that the matches are made in the order defined in `/tmp/words`.
2. The example uses GNU grep and fixed strings for performance reasons. Your mileage may vary with other greps and with regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Awk array.

```
awk 'BEGIN { k[1]="name1"; k[2]="name2"; k[3]="name3" }
{ for (i=1; i<4; ++i) if ($0 ~ k[i]) m[i]=(m[i]?m[i] RS:"") $0 }
END { for(i=1; i<4; ++i) if (m[i]) print m[i] }' file
```

This will produce duplicates if a line matches multiple expressions. It could be optimized somewhat if you need it to be fast; just ask.

Or in Perl:

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN { @k = qw( name1 name2 name3 name4 );
    $k = join("", "(", join("|", @k), ")");
    $r = qr($k); }
  if(m/$r/) { push @{$m{$1}}, $_ }
  END { for $i (@k) { if ($m{$i}) {
    print join("", @{$m{$i}}); } } }' file
```

This is probably somewhat more efficient than the equivalent Awk script.  It will only find one match per line, so it is not exactly equivalent.

Comment: ... but the Awk is decidedly prettier, on the face of it.  The lack of nested arrays in Awk is kind of sad, but the ability to use the backref as an array key in Perl is the real reason I wrote a second version.  I suppose it could be done in Awk as well, albeit not very elegantly.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions! i was really hoping there was something a bit simpler - i'll investigate these suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

One lame solution might be.. Run the grep command multiple times (maybe u can paste it into a shell script and run it multiple times)

```
grep 'name1' file.txt > newfile.txt
grep 'name2' file.txt >> newfile.txt
grep 'name3' file.txt >> newfile.txt
grep 'name4' file.txt >> newfile.txt
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: An easy way to improve this would be `for word in "name1" "name2" "name3" "name4"; do grep "$word" file.txt; done > newfile.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

List item

I was looking same command, but now I figured out.

Step 1: Make file for your grep search. Just paste grep word in file, one grep keyword in one line. For example I make file mySearch.txt.

more mySearch.txt

name2
name3
name1
name4
name2
name1

Step 2: Now use this command
grep -Fwf  mySearch.txt file.txt>newfile.txt
or
cat file.txt|grep -Fwf  mySearch.txt >newfile.txt

Thais command will print all line with name2 first, then name3 and so on and name1 line at the end of newfile.txt.

Answer (score -1):

perl would be better for this kind of search and print.

```
perl -lne '/name1/?push @a,$_:
          (/name2/?push @b,$_:
          (/name3/?push @c,$_:
           /name4/?push @d,$_:next));
          END{print join "\n",@a,@b,@c,@d}' your_file
```

Testde Below:

```
> cat temp
1 name1
2 name2
3 name3
4 name1
5 name4
6 name2
7 name1
> perl -lne '/name1/?push @a,$_:(/name2/?push @b,$_:(/name3/?push @c,$_:/name4/?push @d,$_:next));END{print join "\n",@a,@b,@c,@d}' temp
1 name1
4 name1
7 name1
2 name2
6 name2
3 name3
5 name4
>
```

Good question though :)